# Using output parameters when calling stored procedures with AsyncPoco

Tags: c#, asynchronous, orm, poco

I'm executing a SQL Server stored procedure which returns a single output parameter using AsyncPoco:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateId]
    (@RETVAL VARCHAR(12) OUTPUT) 
AS
    DECLARE @pkgID VARCHAR(12)

    BEGIN
        SELECT @pkgID = 'ABC' + '000'
        SELECT @RETVAL = @pkgID
    END
GO
```

Here's how I'm calling it:

```
var spOutput = new SqlParameter("@RETVAL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
{
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    Size = 12,
};

var sql = $";EXEC [dbo].[GenerateId] @0 OUTPUT";

var response = await _dbAdapter.FetchAsync<dynamic>(sql, new object[] { spOutput });
return (string)spOutput.Value;
```

This is the error I get:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at System.Object.GetType()
>   at AsyncPoco.Database.FormatCommand(String sql, Object[] args) in C:\Aldenteware\AsyncPoco\code\AsyncPoco\Database.cs:line 2279

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
var spOutput = new SqlParameter("@RETVAL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
{
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    Size = 12,
};

var sql = $";EXEC [dbo].[GenerateId] @@RETVAL = @0 OUTPUT";
var sqlClass = new Sql();
var s = sqlClass.Append(sql, spOutput);

var response = await _dbAdapter.ExecuteAsync(s);
return (string)spOutput.Value;
```